# Hide template Word Doc while displaying executed Word Doc?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, interop, mailmerge

In my code below, I start up 2 word instances. One instance I set to my "template", the file for a Mail Merge document that hasn't been run. The other Instance is for a blank document I will use to copy/paste each page from the executed mail merge document into, and then individually save the document.

I make both Word instances visible, then open up my "template" and the blank document for individual saving using each instance. Next I open the Data Source for the MailMerge operation.

Once I Execute the Mail Merge operation, I am left with 3 documents visible on my screen:

1. The original "template" for the Mail Merge
2. The blank document I was using for individual file saving when copy/pasting the Mail Merge sections.
3. The executed mail merge document titled "Form Letters1".

My code processes a while() loop going through and copies each section of "Form Letters1" and pasting it into my document titled "NewDocument.doc". My foreach() loop then updates a database tracking table before generating the filename of "NewDocument.doc" and saving it.

Once the individual section from "Form Letters1" has been saved, I select everything in the newly saved document and clear it out for processing the next section in "Form Letters1".

When all individual sections of "Form Letters1" have been copy/pasted and saved as their own document I hide my "NewDocument.doc" with `oNewWord.Visible = false;`.

My issue here is that on screen I am still showing both the the "template" document for the Mail Merge, and also the "Form Letters1" executed Mail Merge document.

**Is there any way for me to hide the template and keep "Form Letters1" visible? I tried setting `oWord.Visible = false;` before my message box appears, but that hides both the "template" AND "Form Letters1" (the executed Mail Merge document I need to let users review and print).**

```
public void MergeSplitAndReview()
    {
        try
        {
            //MergeDocLibrary mdl = new MergeDocLibrary();
            //mdl.mergeDocument(docSource, docLoc);

            // Mail Merge Template
            Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
            Word.Document oWrdDoc = new Word.Document();
            // New Document Instance
            Word.Application oNewWord = new Word.Application();
            Word.Document oNewWrdDoc = new Word.Document();

            object doNotSaveChanges = Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;

            // Documents must be visible for code to Activate()
            oWord.Visible = true;
            oNewWord.Visible = true;

            Object oTemplatePath = docLoc;
            Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            // Open Mail Merge Template
            oWrdDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(oTemplatePath);

            // Open New Document (Empty)
            // Note: I tried programmatically starting a new word document instead of opening an exisitng "blank",
            //       bu when the copy/paste operation occurred, formatting was way off. The blank document below was
            //       generated by taking a copy of the FullMailMerge.doc, clearing it out, and saving it, thus providing
            //       a kind of formatted "template".
            string newDocument = projectDirectory + "\\NewDocument.doc";
            oNewWrdDoc = oNewWord.Documents.Open(newDocument);

            // Open Mail Merge Datasource
            oWrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(docSource, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
               oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);

            // Execute Mail Merge (Opens Completed Mail Merge Documents Titled "Letters1")
            oWrdDoc.MailMerge.Execute();

            // Save the processed Mail Merge Document for Archiving
            // oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(docTempDir + "FullMailMerge.doc");

            int docCnt = oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections.Count - 1;
            int cnt = 0;
            while (cnt != docCnt)
            {
                cnt++;
                string newFilename = "";

                // Copy Desired Section from Mail Merge
                oWord.ActiveDocument.Sections[cnt].Range.Copy();
                // Set focus to the New Word Doc instance
                oNewWord.Activate();
                // Paste copied range to New Word Doc
                oNewWord.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Paste();

                foreach (ListViewItem lvI in lvData.Items)
                {
                    if (lvI.Checked) // Get first checked lvI in lvData to use for generating filename
                    {
                        updateAddrChngHistory(lvI.SubItems[16].Text);

                        string fileSys = lvI.SubItems[12].Text.ToUpper();
                        string memNo = lvI.SubItems[0].Text;

                        newFilename = fileSys + "%" + memNo + "%" + "" + "%" + "" + "%" + "CORRESPONDENCE%OUTGOING - ACKNOWLEDGEMENT%" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss.ffffff") + ".doc";

                        lvI.Remove(); // Delete from listview the lvI used for newFilename
                        break;        // Break out of foreach loop
                    }
                }

                // Save New Word Doc
                oNewWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(docTempDir + newFilename);
                // Clear New Word Doc
                oNewWord.ActiveDocument.Content.Select();
                oNewWord.Selection.TypeBackspace();
            }
            // Show only the Full Mail Merge Doc. Have user press OK when finished to close documents.
            // Set 'False' in PROD, 'True' in DEV
            // oWord.Visible = false;
            // Hides my new word instance used to save each individual section of the full Mail Merge Doc
            oNewWord.Visible = false;
            MessageBox.Show(new Form() { TopMost = true }, "Click OK when finsihed.");

            oNewWord.ActiveDocument.Close(doNotSaveChanges); // Close the Individual Record Document
            oNewWord.Quit();                                 // Close Word Instance for Individual Record
            oWord.ActiveDocument.Close(doNotSaveChanges);    // Close the Full Mail Merge Document (Currently ALSO closes the Template document)
            oWord.Quit(doNotSaveChanges);                    // Close the Mail Merge Template
            MessageBox.Show("Mail Merge Completed, Individual Documents Saved, Instances Closed.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
            MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
            // Close all Word processes
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winword");
            foreach (var process in processes)
            {
                process.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to show/hide individual documents using, e.g.the equivalent of the following VBA:

```
oWord.ActiveDocument.Windows(1).Visible = false
```

(substituting the appropriate document object instead of ActiveDocument).

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try when I have time tomorrow. For now I ended up just closing all documents when processing was finished then leaving a single instance running to reopen the saved Full Mail Merge for display.